# BigCommerce Stencil Theme Upload

Tags: bigcommerce

After upgrading to the latest version of Stencil CLI, my current theme no longer builds or runs locally (due to missing StencilEditor plugin).

I upgraded the base theme to the latest version of Stencil on GitHub. I am now receiving an error:

`Your theme could not be added at this time. Please try again. (TR-1200)`

The theme passes lint and builds correctly locally. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a server error. You may be able to reattempt later and it will resolve itself.

Comment: @Alyss I don't know it resolved itself - or - I corrected the URL for the theme documentation to a valid URL (?). But in any case, the problem is resolved from our end.